# Basic doubt while using an operator on a wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Say a particle is in state
$\Psi(x, t)$.
Then what is the meaning of
−i$\hbar \partial_x (\Psi(x, t) )$ . I know we have operated the wave function by the momentum operator but what is the significance of the whole result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $\psi(x)$ is a momentum eigenstate, i.e., a state with a well-defined momentum, say $p$, then $-i\hbar \partial_x \psi(x)=p\psi(x)$. Thus, it gives you the wavefunction times the value of the momentum.
- If $\psi(x)$ is not a momentum eigenstate, i.e., a state without a well-defined momentum, then you can write the wavefunction as a superposition of different momentum eigenstates as $\psi(x) = \int dp~c_p e^{ipx}$. Now, $-i\hbar \partial_x \psi(x)=\int dp ~ p c_p e^{ipx}$. This doesn't have a direct physical meaning. However, you can see this resulting wavefunction as a wavefunction which gives you the expectation value of the momentum operator when you take its inner products with the original wavefunction, i.e.,$$\int dx ~\psi^*(x) \big[-i\hbar \partial_x \psi(x) \big]$$$$= \int dp ~p \vert c_p\vert^2 = \langle p \rangle $$.
- Finally, there is a meaning you can associate with $-i\hbar \partial_x \psi(x)$ in the context of translations along space based on the fact that momentum operator is the generator of translations in space (in fact, you just need to know that the momentum operator is $-i\hbar \partial_x$ because that's what the generator of translations in space is). OK, so since $-i\hbar \partial_x$ is the generator of translations in space, $-i\hbar \partial_x\psi(x)$ gives you the rate of change of $\psi(x)$ under infinitesimal translations along $x$ as almost self evident by the presence of $\partial_x$ therein.

Comment: Thank you, so if it's an eigenfunction of momentum operator then the eigenvalue is exactly the momentum of the particle.?

Comment: @YasirSadiq Yes, exactly, that's what the momentum of a particle means in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Thanks dear dvij

Answer (score 1):

You can often think of $\Psi(x,t)$ as a probability amplitude.
Then

$$
\int [\Psi(x,t)]^*[-i\hbar\partial_x\Psi(x,t)] \text{d}x
$$

is the expectation value of momentum in the state $\Psi(x,t)$.

Comment: Thank you fra, but I'm not asking about the scalar product. I'm curious about the above term only.